# Let $X,Y$ be rvs with $E[X] = a, E[Y] = b$. How can I tell if they are independent?

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ are rvs with $E[X] = a, E[Y] = b$. I want to show that either the are independent, not independent, or that we can't tell given the information.

I know that $X,Y$ are independent iff $$P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x)P(Y=y)$$ 
It seems to me unlikely one could derive independence simply know constant expectation and nothing else. However, I am not sure how to prove that there isn't enough information to tell.

Can someone explain whether independence can be shown in this case?

Comment: To prove you can't tell given information: come up with two independent events and two non-independent events that both satisfy the hypotheses.

Comment: Wow, never thought of trying something like that. I can try. Why does that prove you can't tell though? Is it because it shows neither independence nor non-independence are valid hypotheses?

Comment: If you were to prove that all such random variables are independent, e.g., then you would not be able to find specific $X$ and $Y$ with $E[X] = a$ and $E[Y] = b$ that are not independent.